# PHP/MySQL Select the day before and day after a range from the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one called check_ins and another called holidays.

check_ins has a datetime_start and datetime_end columns (in addition to other stuff that isn't needed for this question). The holidays table has a date range of two columns for the start and end of the holiday.

I need to figure out who was in the day prior to and the day directly after the holiday range to determine who gets holiday pay. In other words, I need only results from the table that the same employee was in one day before and one day after, ignoring the rest.

I've been racking my brain all day trying to figure out a way to do this and have found nothing. Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Should I do this via PHP?

Thanks!

Edit: this is what I used and though I had it until I realized that their might be multiple check-ins in a single day:

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(check_ins.Employee_ID), check_ins.ShiftStart_Datetime, check_ins.ShiftEnd_Datetime, holidays.* FROM check_ins, holidays WHERE holidays.ID = 2 AND DATE(DATE_ADD(Datefrom, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = DATE(ShiftStart_Datetime) GROUP BY Employee_ID HAVING count(check_ins.Employee_ID) >1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT check_ins.Employee_ID, check_ins.ShiftStart_Datetime, check_ins.ShiftEnd_Datetime, holidays.* FROM check_ins, holidays WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(Dateto, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = DATE(ShiftStart_Datetime) GROUP BY Employee_ID HAVING count(check_ins.Employee_ID) >1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (inner) join the `check_ins` table twice. Once for the day before the start of the holiday and once for the day after.

If the `datetime_start` and `datetime_end` may have different dates, you need to use `BETWEEN`. Cast both of them to a date instead of a datetime, since you don't care about the time.

Add a `GROUP BY` in case the employee has multiple check ins on one day.

```
SELECT holidays.id AS holiday_id, ci_before.employee_id FROM holidays 
   INNER JOIN check_ins ci_before ON holidays.holiday_start - INTERVAL 1 DAY
       BETWEEN DATE(ci_before.datetime_start) AND DATE(ci_before.datetime_end)
   INNER JOIN check_ins ci_after ON holidays.holiday_end + INTERVAL 1 DAY
       BETWEEN DATE(ci_after.datetime_start) AND DATE(ci_after.datetime_end)
       AND ci_before.employee_id = ci_after.employee_id
GROUP BY ci_before.employee_id
```

### [See the SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f50bb/7)

The used tables are

```
CREATE TABLE `holidays` (id int, holiday_start date, holiday_end date);
CREATE TABLE `check_ins` (employee_id int, datetime_start datetime, datetime_end datetime);
```

`holidays.id` is an ID for a holiday, not an employee.

Comment: The Employee_ID is in the check_ins table, not the holidays table. Would adding that table to the original select not screw up the inner joins? The holidays table just defines the holidays an stores no other information to employees.

Comment: Of course the employee_id is in the check_ins table. The SQL says `ci_before.employee_id` where `ci_before` is an alias `check_ins`. You must be reading the SQL wrong. Please look closely at the SQL and the SQL fiddle!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning the more advanced stuff. I have the SQL functioning (As in, no errors, but no records), but I really have no idea when it comes to INNER JOIN. I know that I have records the day before and the day after, say the holiday "Thanksgiving" in the holidays table, from 2013-11-27 to 2013-11-30, but I get zero records from that query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The holiday table has an ID field. You can add `WHERE holiday.id = 2` before the group by to select Thanksgiving. If it's not working in your case please create an SQL fiddle yourself and I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm an idiot that needs sleep. Never mind, I figured out what was wrong. Thanks so much for the input, your solution worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via php in 2 queries, but why would you... this'll be fun!

```
SELECT * FROM check_ins
    LEFT JOIN holidays AS holi_before 
        ON ( 
            datediff(holi_before.datetime_end,check_ins.datetime_end) <= 1
        )
    LEFT JOIN holidays AS holi_after
        ON (
            holi_before.id = holi_after.id 
            AND datediff(holi_after.datetime_end,check_ins.datetime_end) >= 1
        )
```

That should about do it (might need to tweak the datediff comparison a bit to get it exactly right.)

haven't test it, but i hope it gives you the right push :-)

Comment: I should be more clear. The check_ins column Employee_ID is the column that I need. Aside from that, I get an unknown column on holy_before.Datefrom  using this: SELECT * FROM check_ins
    LEFT JOIN holidays AS holi_before 
        ON ( 
            datediff(holy_before.Datefrom,Date(check_ins.ShiftStart_Datetime)) <= 1
        )
    LEFT JOIN holidays AS holi_after
        ON (
            check_ins.Employee_ID = check_ins.Employee_ID
            AND datediff(holy_after.Dateto,Date(check_ins.ShiftStart_Datetime)) >= 1
        )  Thanks for the help! - I've edited the original question.

Comment: was a typo, holy instead of holi